# Where can I share my cool scripts?

Tags: bash, share

I've written a few (what I consider to be cool) bash scripts (that are specific to the Raspberry Pi), and I'd like to share them with the community.

Is there a jsfiddle-like site where I can put up the scripts?

Maybe even a community-based, cloud-sourced, site would be good for this, maybe in a **wiki** style. Does anyone know of one like this?

I just added a very brief [script](https://jsfiddle.net/0y563ocg/) to JSFiddle to see if it'd work. Please let me know if you guys would use this. Or if it's just a horrible idea.

Comment: If they do something useful you could ask and answer your own question, e.g. Q. how do I do X on the Raspberry Pi. A. Here is how to do X on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: github, and youmay want to publize them by writing a post for our blog.

Comment: @joan I've kinda done the ask and answer to separate parts of cool scripts that I've created on here, and on unix.stackexchange, but was looking for a more dedicated site to put it all into one - without seeming to be repeating myself.

Comment: Show them to girls on first dates.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43527/discussion-on-question-by-jim-where-can-i-share-my-cool-scripts).

Comment: Where did you end up putting them? You can't just leave us hanging.

Comment: @MasterOfBinary: right now, most of them are on my Pi in `/usr/local/bin/` subdirectories. The most apt (please excuse the pun) place for them is probably on git, however, I just can't get my head around how to use it. Downloading a copy just to post a shell script doesn't make sense to me. I considered making a new site for it, but just don't have the time to code & market this site.

Comment: Maybe a wiki-style site would be good for this.. editing Question to ask just this.

Comment: @MasterOfBinary Check out http://bash.blyzz.com/ - added a comments section now too so feel free to add comments (I've not enabled moderation _yet_ and hope it will not become necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in frustration, I've thrown a little site together that has one script on it so far.

It's very much a static site. I plan on adding a comments section on it later, but for now, it's very much non-interactive.

If you've any feedback on it (positive or negative) let me know.

**http://bash.blyzz.com/**

I hope the stackexchange sites don't mind me imitating some of the styling.

Answer (score 13):

1. [Github.com](http://github.com)
2. [gitlab.org](http://gitlab.org)
3. [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org)

anywhere code related really

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something designed specifically for RPi though.

Comment: well the fun thing is with github, I myself have lots of programs on github specificly for the RPI 2b
it allows everyone to contribute aswell if needed :)

Comment: Awesome, share the link pls. The reason I'm kinda avoiding github is that I don't fully 'get' it. Maybe a bad reason to avoid it - I know. I'm just the kind of guy that likes JS on JSFiddle, and PHP on PHPFiddle, etc.

Comment: https://github.com/ppigmans

just simple lightweight programs, installers, GUI's and fixes of other programs

Comment: oh and Project-trinity on my front page is an A.I. WIP

Comment: and everything is mostly in my native language, dutch XD

Answer (score 9):

To have a jsfiddle-like shareable link for your scripts, create a Github account, and save your scripts as GISTs: https://gist.github.com/ You will be able to update them in the future if you need.

Regarding a place to post them, I think you are looking for the wrong thing. You want a place to share Raspian stuff, not Raspberry right? RaspberyPI is just the computer, if it's running some other OS your scripts might not fit.

You might find a place to share your scripts links in
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=66 or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: You're right, it is for Raspbian and wouldn't run on other RPi O/Ss, however, at the same time, some of the commands wouldn't work on non-RPi Linux distros. However, as mentioned in the OP, I'd have liked to have a RPI-centric place for bash scripts. I guess I should have used "any" scripts, not specifically "bash", to include scripts written for other RPi distros.

Answer (score 6):

One place to go to - if you care about some explaining of those scripts too - would be our *official<sup>+</sup>* blog [Piversify](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/):

> Piversify is a blog dedicated to the Raspberry Pi, written by members of the raspberrypi.stackexchange.com community.

Here's the [procedure](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/we-started-a-blog?cb=1) how to contribute.

---

<sup>+</sup>  <sup><sub>Piversify is not hosted by or otherwise linked to StackExchange itself or the Stack Exchange Inc. It is merely run by the community and its moderators here without being legally tied to StackExchange.</sub></sup>

Comment: I'll check it out - tumblr blocked in my office :-(

Comment: why is the blog *official* and not just official?

Comment: @JaromandaX, *Piversify is a blog dedicated to the Raspberry Pi, written by members of the raspberrypi.stackexchange.com community.* It is however not hosted by or otherwise linked to StackExchange itself or Stack Exchange Inc. So it is merely run by the community and its moderators here without being legally tied to StackExchange.

Comment: thanks - I always look twice when I see *italicised* statements like that - now I'll take a look :p

Answer (score 1):

I had the same ideas before and after some research I found that we can share it as an **open source** project in **Github**.

That's why I have created new Repository for this purpose and anybody can contribute in it.

It's the project of usage Raspberry Pi & Co in home usage.

If it's interesting for you - [follow this link](https://github.com/romankh3/raspberrypi-home-ecosystem).